# Errors running apt-get update and apt-get install mysql-server

Tags: apt, aptitude, amazon-ec2

Since yesterday I've been trying to run

```
apt-get update
```

unsuccessfully in Ubuntu instances I am creating on the EC2.

In specific I've been getting these errors:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/universe/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@ip-10-168-230-63:/etc/apt#
```

Also trying to install mysql-server, I've been getting errors:

```
root@ip-10-168-230-63:/etc/apt# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libhtml-template-perl mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libhtml-template-perl mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.1MB/12.2MB of archives.
After this operation, 29.5MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main mysql-server-core-5.1 amd64 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main mysql-server-5.1 amd64 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  403  Forbidden
Err http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main mysql-server all 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1
  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.1/mysql-server-core-5.1_5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.1/mysql-server-5.1_5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.1/mysql-server_5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1_all.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@ip-10-168-230-63:/etc/apt#
```

I did run

```
apt-get update --fix-missing
```

without any luck.

Any ideas?

I have done these tasks many times on Ubuntu Linux instances running in the AWS EC2 without any problems.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: maverick (10.10) has reached EndOfLife in April 2012, see [http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/04/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-end-of-life-reached-on-april-10-2012/](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/04/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-end-of-life-reached-on-april-10-2012/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix was to add these lines to sources.list:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main multiverse universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main multiverse universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main multiverse universe
```

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Be wary: this will also stop working one day. You already will -not- receive security updates through archive.ubuntu.com. I would advise upgrading to or re-installing 12.04 if you want to keep LTS'ing.

Answer (score 15):

This was a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/987182) with Amazon S3. To fix this, just run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Even though this wasn't the answer to OP's original issue (using outdated LTS), I'm on 12.04, was getting this same error, and your solution fixed it, so +1

Comment: He had problems running `apt-get update` so your recommended solution is to run `apt-get update`?!

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat has reached end of life (EOL) as of April 10 2012, which means there are no further updates (not even security fixes) and the package archives are moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, which is the reason for the error you are seeing.

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and [fix your package sources](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/22375). Note that you need to also remove the `us-west-1.ec2` prefix: there are no dedicated EC2 package servers for EOL releases.

Answer (score 3):

With this advice, and other notes that mentioned "archive" changed to "old-releases" the following snippet helped me move forward.

```
sudo sed 's@http://archive\.ubuntu\.com/@http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/@' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then I was able to install whatever package it is I needed (in my case php5-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

try to add addtional source

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or install LAMP via tasksel

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

**Security Groups -> Outbound**

```
*   ALL Traffic ALL     ALL     0.0.0.0/0   Allow
```

Please allow Outbound, if you want to connect to external servers like google.com
or even want to update- sudo apt-get update

You can allow the outbound using AWS front-end goto Security Groups -> Outbound

Make sure you select the right group for your AWS instance