# APT - Error in installing mysql-server in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: server, apt, mysql

I'm trying to install `mysql-server`. I followed the steps discussed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install, but when I try to install it I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libmecab2v5 mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libmecab2v5 mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-server mysql-server
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 108 not upgraded.
Need to get 268 kB/25.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 202 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main libaio1 amd64 0.3.110-1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.90.159.172 80]
Err http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe libmecab2v5 amd64 0.996-1.1ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.90.159.172 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libaio/libaio1_0.3.110-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.90.159.172 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mecab/libmecab2v5_0.996-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.90.159.172 80]

E: Aborting install.
```

Comment: have your run `apt-get update` before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors running apt-get update and apt-get install mysql-server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244822/errors-running-apt-get-update-and-apt-get-install-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the mirror. I get the 403 Forbidden from the same mirror for about 50 packages while trying to install `gnome-session-fallback` and many other things. Does anybody know who owns this mirror, how to contact them, and how to report an issue? I would love to be able to install software without breaking my sources again.

Some tips here might help: [E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead after apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used)
Especially (if you're using ubuntu-desktop): open Ubuntu Software Center, go to Edit in the menu, Software sources, and change "Servers for Phillippines" to "Main server."

That seemed to help a bit, but I still have other apt issues to workout. Something about held packages, and failing to find "restricted/sources/Sources" in release file. Yay.